# How to process files each with own header of different column count with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have :

1. millions of files on s3
2. format is not compatible with https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv because it is awful DSV specification which needs special treatment, header line starts with a special character and each file can contain multiple headers in it (idiosyncrasy of the provider), usually count of columns change in time even within a single file (if it has multiple headers in it) ...
3. each file has a header but headers change (different fields/columns)
4. for performance reasons I need to do smth. like this : `read.text("s3n://2016/01/*")`

I cannot find a way how to grab the header and it's corresponding lines that follow to process it together. Imho custom `Partitioner` that would partition data per file cannot be written and rdd/dataset/dataframe API doesn't provide any means that could do this...

Any idea? I can use Spark 2.0.0. It seems to me that Spark isn't much friendly to DSV files with headers, especially if the headers vary...

Comment: For performance reasons you absolutely do not want to do `read.text("s3n://2016/01/*")`. See http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219.

Comment: In any case, please give more details of the file format. The most generic way would be to implement your own reader.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest strategy would be to organize your files in some sane way for further processing, or build up a directory of which file is of what type, then use that to drive building the RDDs.

See http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219 for examples of calling the amazon s3 client from inside an rdd. You could use that to build up that directory.

Comment: Hey, I read that kinja.com article, I'll definitely do that once I add more machines. I updated the format description. I think that I will "copy/paste" the code from `spark-csv` that work with partitions and allows me to iterate partitions where each represents a single file ...

Comment: Just one additional question, is it possible to repartition RDD by files? So that I'd reliably get a single-partition-per-file ? Instead of implementing custom DataSource ?

Comment: I'm little bit confuse because `spark-csv` library is using just `sc.textFile(...)` and then it does `rdd.mapPartitions { lines => lines.head; ... }` which doesn't necessarily have to resolve to single-partition-per-file` , right ?

Comment: @lisak The point of an RDD is that it represents a homogenous sequence. If you're trying to have a non-homogenous RDD you're probably doing something wrong. Partitions have nothing to do with files. Once your data are loaded they are independent of their source.

Comment: We don't use hdfs (and don't want to) so files do influence partitions in our system because we usually partition the rdd by fileName/filePath in the end so that each machine could safely store data to file and do something with it...

Comment: @lisak So? Who said anything about HDFS?

Comment: we use s3 storage with logically partitioned data like `2016/05/21/19/partition.json` so in order to output spark result in there I must be concerned about relationship between partitions and files ...

Comment: It honestly sounds like you're trying to do mapreduce style computation using spark. It's not that it can't be done, and it's not that it won't be faster. It will be fiddlier, though, until you figure out how to work with the grain of spark's abstractions.